# A thread start on a button click and ending the thread with another button click

Tags: java, android, thread-safety

Sir Please help me to  add a thread that starts on a button click and ends the thread with another button click. In between I have a sound playing till the thread stops.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this simple code:

```
    final volatile boolean toExit = false;
    final Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(!toExit){
                // Your code
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            t.start();
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            toExit = true;
        }
    });
```

The thread will stop after button2 clicked and run to `while(!toExit)`.

Answer (score 1):

Threads stop method is deprecated.
The best solution will be having a boolean variable in the run method.

Your Thread:

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IndexProcessor.class);
private volatile boolean running = true;

public void terminate() {
    running = false;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (running) {
        try {
            //Your code that needs to be run multiple times

            LOGGER.debug("Processing");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception", e);
            running = false;
        }
    }

}
}
```

In your Activity:

```
MyThread t=new Thread();


 findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        t.start();
    }
});

findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        t.terminate();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use Below Code

```
public class SomeBackgroundProcess implements Runnable {

Thread backgroundThread;

public void start() {
   if( backgroundThread == null ) {
      backgroundThread = new Thread( this );
      backgroundThread.start();
   }
}

public void stop() {
   if( backgroundThread != null ) {
      backgroundThread.interrupt();
   }
}

public void run() {
    try {
       Log.i("Thread starting.");
       while( !backgroundThread.interrupted() ) {
          doSomething();
       }
       Log.i("Thread stopping.");
    } catch( InterruptedException ex ) {
       // important you respond to the InterruptedException and stop processing 
       // when its thrown!  Notice this is outside the while loop.
       Log.i("Thread shutting down as it was requested to stop.");
    } finally {
       backgroundThread = null;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you